# Is it possible to customize the logout page or create a custom logout page in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, logout

At the moment if the user navigates to the default `logout` page it looks like this:

[image: Logout]

This is not consistent with the theme of my website so I would like this content inside my own custom page. Can this be done?

I have a plugin installed **My Theme Plugin** which is designed to let me specify a logout page but I do not know how to construct it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Look into the `logout_url` hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/logout_url/

Comment: @disinfor Thanks for that. If we redirect to our own page how do we implement the same functionality as the original - with the prompt?

Comment: Since you can redirect to any page you want, you simply add any content to that page. The logout prompt would use `wp_logout_url()`, e.g. `<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a>` for the actual logout link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this may help others, I'm adding my comments as an answer.

You need to initially use the `logout_url` filter - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/logout_url/

This will allow you to set up a page when a user clicks on the `logout` link. Next, you simply create the page however you need to (basic WordPress page, special template, etc.).

On that page you would use `wp_logout_url()` to set the link for the `Are you sure you want to logout` text. e.g.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Logout</a>
```

This would redirect the user to the home page after they've logged out.

Edit: shortcode to add to content:

```
function wpso58817718_add_logout_link( $atts ){
    return '<a href="' . wp_logout_url( home_url() ) . '">Logout</a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'logout_link', 'wpso58817718_add_logout_link' );
```

Then you can do `[logout_link]`

You'll have to update the end URL `wp_logout_url( home_url() )` if you don't want it to go to the home page.

Comment: Thanks. :) How would you insert the content you just referred to into the custom page? As a "snippet -> shortcode"?

Comment: Why not use regular content? How you implement it is completely up to you and the needs of the site. I can't really answer that for you.

Comment: What I mean is, how are you supposed to put that link / php content into an actual page via the Gutenberg editor?

Comment: Ah, I see. Updated the answer with a shortcode, which is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to redirect user to your specific url after logout

```
add_action('wp_logout','ps_redirect_after_logout');
function ps_redirect_after_logout(){
         wp_redirect( 'your url here' );
         exit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But my question relates to the actual "logout process".